# solving iterative equations in matlab

Tags: matlab

For a heat exchanger modelling, I would like to give different equations into the Matlab, and solve the unknowns with respect to equations' relationship. For example these are different equations, and parameters:

.
.
.

```
syms D L n Aflow X
Ga=m1a/(pi*D^2/4*n);
Red=Ga*D/nua;
F1=(delpaa-(Ga^2*(1/rhoao-1/rhoai)))*rhoa*0.5*D/(L*Ga^2)-f;  %%Equation 1

%%Pressure Drop in Gas Side
delpag=Pin1g-Pout1g;
rhogo=(Pout1g/287*Tout1g)
rhogi=rhogo*Pin1g*Tout1g/(Pout1g*Tin1g);
rhog=0.5*(rhogo+rhogi);

Gg=m1g/(Aflow);
X=Do/D;
Dh=4*Aflow/n*pi*Do;
Redh=Gg*Dh/nug;
F2=(delpag-(Gg^2*(1/rhogo-1/rhogi)))*rhog*0.5*Dh/(L*Gg^2)-fo;

ratio=Redh/Red;
fo=f*ratio^-0.2;   %f=0.046*Redh^-0.2

F3=0.95*Ga*0.5*f*(power(Pra,-2/3))-h;
F4=cpg*Gg*0.5*fo*(power(Prg,-2/3))-ho;

F5=(UA/(h*n*pi*D*L))+(UA/(ho*n*pi*Do*L))-1;

% UAho=1-Uah;
Adim=Aflow/n*D^2;

S = solve(F1,F2,F3,F4,F5,D, L, n, Aflow, X);
S.D
S.L
S.n
S.Aflow
S.X
```

.
.
.

"Undefined function or variable 'Do'. X=Do/D;"

But, I already put the D and X to the syms so, it should guess also the Do, shouldn't it?

Comment: Either write your equations in order so that variables are defined before being used, or do a bit simultaneous symbolic solution. The first option is much preferred, even if you have to solve a few small systems of equations along the way.

Comment: The thing is, Matlab should look to the equations, and make guess within a tolerance; order is not important. How can I implement the second solution?

Comment: Matlab runs each line of code separately, one at a time. Look up `solve`.

Comment: The values Matlab should guess "D","L","n","Aflow","X". Therefore, I indicated them as "syms"; however I guess I also need to tell the Matlab, which syms should be solved with a particular equation which would be very hard I assume?

Comment: You haven't defined `Do` when you use it. Define it first.

Comment: Thank you very much David. Do you think this problem could be solved by for loops?Basically I have 4 design parameters, and I want this parameters compatible with the equations.

Comment: It really depends. You might be able to put your 4 parameters in as symbolic variables, solve for the 5 variables in terms of those 4, and convert the results into anonymous functions taking the 4 parameters as input. That would be the nicest way of doing it.